# Converting lengthy if... else if... else... block to a switch

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm learning C. For a class exercise, I'm trying to convert a lengthy `if... else if... else...` block into more efficient C code using a `switch` statement. There are two issues:

1. The code must maintain support for `/` or `-`, and must also support the variable length of `/c`, `/c.abc`, where the `.` and anything following it are optional.
2. `char *argv[]` can accept unix filepaths.

The existing block looks like this:

```
#include <strings.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;

    for (i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        if (!strcasecmp(argv[i], "/a") || !strcasecmp(argv[i], "-a"))
            /* Do something */
        else if (!strcasecmp(argv[i], "/b") || !strcasecmp(argv[i], "-b"))
            /* Do something */
        else if (!strncasecmp(argv[i], "/c", 2) || !strncasecmp(argv[i], "-c", 2))
            /* Do something */
        else if (!strcasecmp(argv[i], "/d") || !strcasecmp(argv[i], "-d"))
            /* Do something */
        else if ((argv[i][0] == '/' || argv[i][0] == '-') && (!argv[i][2] || argv[i][2] == '.'))
        {
            /* Error message */
            return 1;
        }
    else
    {
        /* For unix filepaths. */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My initial thought was to use a `switch` on `argv[i][1]` to avoid the `/` or `-` issue. For example:

```
if ((argv[i][0] == '/' || argv[i][0] == '-') && (!argv[i][2] || argv[i][2] == '.'))
{
    switch(argv[i][1])
    {
    case 'a':
        /* Do something */
        break;
    case 'b':
        /* Do something */
        break;
    case 'c':
        /* Do something and process any characters after the . */
        break;
    case 'd':
        /* Do something */
        break;
    default:
        /* Error message */
        return 1;
    }
}
else
{
    /* Unix filepaths and anything else. */
}
```

So far, the `switch` achieves most of the task. Unfortunately, the statement `if ((argv[i][0] == '/' || argv[i][0] == '-') && (!argv[i][2] || argv[i][2] == '.'))` will also accept invalid flags such as `/a.`.

Removing the variable length case (e.g. `/c` or `/c.abc`) from the `switch` is another possibility, but then I'm not sure how to ensure that the other cases have a string length of two chars without also accepting `/c` as valid.

Is there a better or more efficient method of converting the `if... else if... else...` block to a `switch`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to move away from if elses? Switches are more efficient but they dont fit your use case.

Comment: Replace `(!argv[i][2] || argv[i][2] == '.'))` with checking the first case only for switches that don't allow `.`

Comment: You could also use getopt: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html

Comment: Take into account that any option starting with `/` can be a filepath too.

Comment: @AzeemBande-Ali The purpose of the exercise was to make the code more efficient or, as far as possible, to improve it. Isn't repeatedly calling `strcasecmp` highly inefficient?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Yes, that is a problem -- and definitely a limitation of my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your use-case I don't think you will save much work by having
a switch especially when you add error handling

try first to split up the work into functions to make your main
more readable

do one function that checks the syntax e.g.

```
int syntaxOk(char* arg)
{
  if ( (strlen(arg) < 2) // too short
     || (arg[0] != '-' && arg[0] != '/') // invalid format
  {
    printSyntax();
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

and one function to write the available syntax

```
void printSyntax()
{ ... }
```

in your main, have a ptr to the argument to make it more readable:

```
char* arg = argv[i];
```

now convert the actual command char to lower case (ctype.h)

```
int ch = tolower( arg[1] );
```

you may need to extract the optional variable length command
so have a buffer where we can put that, like under 'c' so make
a function out of it

```
int doC(char* argv)
{
  size_t len = strlen(argv);
  if ( len > 2 && arg[2] == '.' )
  {
    char cOption[64] = {0};
    strncpy(cOption, arg + 3, sizeof(cOption));
    // do something
    return 1;
  }
  else if ( len == 2 )
  {
    // do something else?
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    printSyntax();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

you can dynamically make cOption depend on the size of the argument but I leave that for you to try. e.g. `char* cOption = malloc(len+1);` instead of a fixed size or depending on your compiler version you could use a variable sized array.

then your switch statement would look something like this:

```
switch (ch)
{
  case 'a': 
    doA();
    break;
  case 'b':
    doB();
    break;
  case 'c': 
    if (!doC(argv))
    {
      printSyntax();
    }
    break;
  case 'd':
    doD();
    break;
  default:
    printSyntax();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Wow. So while it is possible to avoid using `if... else if... else...` statements, it isn't so practical in real terms. Thanks for providing such a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by considering only one character of `argv[i]` at a time:

```
#include <strings.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
   int i;

   for (i=1; i<argc; i++)
      {
      switch(argv[i][0])
         {
         case '/':
         case '-':
            switch(argv[i][1])
               {
               case '\0':
                  /* No further characters in argv[i]; Do something? Print error? */
                  /* As per suggestion of @Mohit Jain. */
                  break;

               case 'a':
                  /* Do something */;
                  break;

               case 'b':
                  /* Do something */;
                  break;

               case 'c':
                  /* Do something */;
                  break;

               case 'd':
                  /* Do something */;
                  break;

               default:
                  if(!argv[i][2] || ('.' == argv[i][2])) // a little danger here...
                     {
                     /* Error message */
                     return 1;
                     }
                  else
                     {
                     /* For unix filepaths. */
                     }
                  break;
               }
            break;

         default:
            /* Error message */
            return 1;
         }
      }

   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: In inner switch, having a case for `\0` would be nice to avoid any danger.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice @MohitJain.  I have edited the answer to add that feature.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Very impressive. Now I understand why using `if... else if...  else...` blocks make this easier, despite the (slight?) loss of efficiency.